# How can I make the code-behind of UserControls inherit a base class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I've got a **page manager** that keeps a collection of pages (usercontrols), sends itself to each page which can thus call its **SwitchPage** method at anytime enabling me to put in links from one page to another. This **works well** and allows me to have a quick menu etc.

```
public partial class PageManager : UserControl
{
    private Dictionary<string, UserControl> Pages = new Dictionary<string, UserControl>();

    private string defaultPageIdCode = "page1";
    private UserControl currentPage;
    private string currentPageIdCode;

    public PageManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadPages();
        SwitchPage(defaultPageIdCode);
    }

    private void LoadPages()
    {
        Pages.Add("page1", new Page1(this));
        Pages.Add("page2", new Page2(this));
    }

    public void SwitchPage(string pageIdCode)
    {
        currentPageIdCode = pageIdCode;
        currentPage = Pages[pageIdCode];
        PageArea.Content = currentPage;
    }
}
```

However, each page (UserControl) has repeated functionality in it, e.g. saving the PageManager object internally, which I would like to put in a base class:

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestPageManager23434.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Background="White" 
             Width="400"
             Height="400"                
                >
        <TextBlock Text="this is page1"/>
        <Button Content="go to page 2" Click="Button_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="200"
                Height="30"
                />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Page1 : UserControl
{
    private PageManager pageManager;

    public Page1(PageManager pageManager)
    {
        this.pageManager = pageManager;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pageManager.SwitchPage("page2");
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestPageManager23434.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Background="White"
                Width="400"
                Height="400"
                >
        <TextBlock Text="this is page2"/>
        <Button Content="go back to page 1" Click="Button_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Width="250"
                Height="30"
                />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Page2 : UserControl
{
    private PageManager pageManager;

    public Page1(PageManager pageManager)
    {
        this.pageManager = pageManager;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pageManager.SwitchPage("page1");
    }
}
```

**How can make each UserControl inherit a base class?** It doesn't work since each UserControl has XAML which can't be inherited. And if I try to inherit from a plain class that inherits UserControl then it tells me:

> Partial declarations of
>   'TestPageManager23434.Page2' must not
>   specify different base classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of declaring the root element as UserControl, declare it as your derived class. You will need to specify the namespace as well e.g.

```
<local:PageBase x:Class="TestPageManager23434.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestPageManager23434">
</local:PageBase>
```

Comment: Obviously the class in the code behind should then also inherit from the same base class...

Comment: Actually, I discovered the other day that you don't need to specify the base class in the code behind, and Resharper will actually flag it as a redundancy. Only one part of a partial class definition must specify the base class, thought its fine to specify it on multiple parts as long as they match.